# Добавить кусок html кода в javascript и вывести на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется калькулятор на jQuery и мне необходимо добавить в него кусок html кода, а потом вывести его на странице.

Вот так выводится результат:

```
$('#total_amount').text(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(totalAmount) + ' ₽');
```

В html выводится таким образом:

`<div id="total_amount"></div>`

Так как символ рубля в текущем шрифте не отображается на айфонах, то его нужно обернуть в span с другим шрифтом.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы в js вместо ' ₽' подставить `<span class="ruble">₽</span>`.

Поменять шрифт у всего div блока я не могу из-за того, что в рублевом шрифте имеются только начертания символа рубля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#total_amount').html(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(totalAmount) + ' <span class="ruble">₽</span>'
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Mfkboy Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.